# TestNG with Powermockito failing for static methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, testng, powermock

I am trying to add unit-testing to a legacy report-generation code using TestNG and Powermockito.

```
import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertTrue;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.stub;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.mockito.Matchers;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;

@PrepareForTest(ConfigReader.class)
public class defTest{
    @Test
    public void testGetPartsSuccessful() throws Exception {
        TrendsReportData reportGenerator = new TrendsReportData();

        TreeMap<Calendar, String> t = new TreeMap<Calendar, String>();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String b = "234";
        t.put(c, b);
        Properties properties = new Properties();

       properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MetricTest.properties"));
        MetricDAO dao = Mockito.mock(MetricDAO.class);
        Mockito.when(
                          dao.getMetricData(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString(),
                                          Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.any(Calendar.class),
                                          Matchers.any(Calendar.class))).thenReturn(t);
        //stub (PowerMockito.method(ConfigReader.class, "readFile")).toReturn(properties);//line 36
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ConfigReader.class); //line 37
        Mockito.when(ConfigReader.readFile(Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(properties);//line 38
        reportGenerator.setMetricDao(dao);
        reportGenerator.prepareMonthStats();
        //assert file here
    }
}
```

This code is producing the following output:

```
[testng] org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
[testng] Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
[testng] -> at .....defTest.testGetPartsSuccessful(defTest.java:38)
[testng] You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
.
.
.
[testng]    at myclasspackage.myclassname(class_name.java:38)
[testng]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[testng]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[testng]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[testng]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[testng]    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
[testng]    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:691)
[testng]    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:883)
[testng]    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1208)
[testng]    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
[testng]    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:613)
[testng]    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
[testng]    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
[testng]    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
[testng]    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
[testng]    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
[testng]    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1137)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1062)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:974)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1282)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1246)
```

if I comment out line 37 and 38 and use line 36 instead, it works fine but it doesn't produce the desired output i.e. it is not mocking the static method of ConfigReader, but it IS mocking non-static method of MetricDAO.

I've looked into answers provided on other similar questions, but none of them worked. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage) documentation your test class should be extended from `PowerMockTestCase`. There is also mentioned to add this method to your test class:

```
 @ObjectFactory
 public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
     return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
 }
```

But none of these changes worked for me :(

Therefore I switched to JMockit and it is working like a charm. Mocks written in Mockito are working fine alongside JMockit's partial mocking of static method.